# Interactive Multi-Filterable Dash Plotly GIS Map-- Figure Not Working

Tags: python, json, bigdata, gis, plotly-dash

Hello Stack Exchange,

For the life of me I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong at this point. I'm a beginner programmer so i'm proud of getting here; however if there are other solutions that are more effective please feel free to suggest.

Data Files:

- [gdf_final_serial](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ExsHA8df_tnJjkwDoz4eHL-bH--QtT_m/view?usp=sharing)
- ^This is an abridged version as the actual dataset is ~680K Rows
- [geo_school](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14bfmhwXDcbh9a7T8IgmeXnWTGR6d1jV6/view?usp=sharing)
- ^Json being used

What I **need** the Dash app to do:

- Work as a Multi-Filterable GIS Map in regards to fields listed (County, District Name, Age, RE, Quartiles, Housing Insecure)
- Based on the filters chosen, update the px.choropleth_mapbox with the accurate count of 'points'.

*Let's jump into the code*.
I'm also running this on a Google Colab Notebook.

```
filename_1 = root_path+"schoolDistrictBoundaries_Fixed.json"
file = open(filename_1)
schoolDistricts = gpd.read_file(file)
```

^^ being ran in a global cell

```
import dash
import dash.dependencies
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

px.set_mapbox_access_token(mapbox_access_token)

###   Creating gdf_final_serial

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geo_school["features"]).merge(joined, on="OBJECTID").set_index("OBJECTID") #GeoJson Join to Joined Dataframe
cleaned_geo_df = geo_df[["geometry_x", "CountyName_x", "RE", "QUARTILES", "HOUSING_INSECURE", "County", "Age", "DistrictName_x"]] #Picks the right columns
geo_df_final = cleaned_geo_df.rename(columns={"CountyName_x": "CountyName", "geometry_x": "geometry", 'DistrictName_x': 'DistrictName'}) #Changing Column Names
geo_df_final.to_pickle(root_path+"geo_df_final") #Write to drive as a pickle to serialize
df_final_serial = pd.read_pickle(root_path+"geo_df_final") #Read as DataFrame
gdf_final_serial = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data = df_final_serial, geometry= "geometry", crs = "epsg:4326") #Turn into GeoPandas DataFrame and set the geometry and crs


re_indicators = gdf_final_serial.RE.unique()
county_indicators = gdf_final_serial.CountyName.unique()
age_indicators = gdf_final_serial.Age.unique()
district_indicators = gdf_final_serial.DistrictName.unique()

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]
app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Label("County"),
                dcc.Checklist(
                    id="county",
                    options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in county_indicators],
                    value=[]
                ),
                html.Label("District Name"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="dname",
                    options=[],
                    value=[],
                    multi=True,
                ),
                html.Label("Age"),
                dcc.Dropdown(id="age", 
                             options=[], 
                             value=[],
                             multi = True),
                html.Label("RE"),
                dcc.Dropdown(id="re", 
                             options=[], 
                             value=[], 
                             multi = True),
                html.Label("Quartiles"),
                dcc.Dropdown(id="quartiles", 
                             options=[], 
                             value=[], 
                             multi=True),
                html.Label("Housing"),
                dcc.Dropdown(id="housing", 
                             options=[], 
                             value=[], 
                             multi=True),
                dcc.Graph(id="my_map", figure={})])
            ]
        )

@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("dname", "options"), 
  dash.dependencies.Input("county", "value")
)
def choose_county(county_pick): 
  if len(county_pick) > 0: 
      dff=gdf_final_serial[gdf_final_serial.CountyName.isin(county_pick)]
  else: 
      raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
  return [{"label": i, "value": i} for i in (dff.DistrictName.unique())]

@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("dname", "value"),
  dash.dependencies.Input("dname", "options"),
)
def set_city_value(available_options_dname):
  return [x["value"] for x in available_options_dname]


@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("age", "options"), 
  dash.dependencies.Input("dname", "value")
)
def dname_age_picker(choose_dname):
  print(choose_dname)
  if len(choose_dname) > 0:
    dff = gdf_final_serial[gdf_final_serial.DistrictName.isin(choose_dname)]
  else:
    raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
  return [{"label": i, "value": i} for i in (dff.Age.unique())]


@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("age", "value"),
  dash.dependencies.Input("age", "options"),
)
def set_age_value(available_options_age):
  return [x["value"] for x in available_options_age]


@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("re", "options"), 
  dash.dependencies.Input("age", "value")
)
def age_re_picker(choose_age):
  if len(choose_age) > 0:
    dff = gdf_final_serial[gdf_final_serial.Age.isin(choose_age)].dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any', subset = ["RE"])
  else:
    raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
  return [{"label": i, "value": i} for i in (dff.RE.unique())]

@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("re", "value"),
  dash.dependencies.Input("re", "options")
)
def set_re_value(available_options_re):
  return [x["value"] for x in available_options_re]


@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("quartiles", "options"), 
  dash.dependencies.Input("re", "value")
)
def re_quartile_picker(choose_re_value):
  if len(choose_re_value) >= 0:
    dff = gdf_final_serial[gdf_final_serial.RE.isin(choose_re_value)].dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any', subset = ["QUARTILES"])
  else:
    raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
  return [{"label": i, "value": i} for i in (dff.QUARTILES.unique())]

@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("quartiles", "value"),
  dash.dependencies.Input("quartiles", "options"),
)
def set_quart_value(available_options_quart):
  return [x["value"] for x in available_options_quart]

@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("housing", "options"), 
  dash.dependencies.Input("quartiles", "value")
)
def quart_picker(choose_quart_value):
  if len(choose_quart_value) >= 0:
      dff = gdf_final_serial[gdf_final_serial.QUARTILES.isin(choose_quart_value)]
  else:
      raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
  return [{"label": i, "value": i} for i in (dff.HOUSING_INSECURE.unique())]

@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("housing", "value"),
  dash.dependencies.Input("housing", "options"),
)
def set_housing_value(available_options_housing):
  return [x["value"] for x in available_options_housing]

@app.callback(
  dash.dependencies.Output("my_map", "figure"),
  [dash.dependencies.Input("housing", "value"), 
  dash.dependencies.Input("quartiles", "value"), 
  dash.dependencies.Input("re", "value"),
  dash.dependencies.Input("age", "value"),
  dash.dependencies.Input("dname", "value"),
  dash.dependencies.Input("county", "value")]
)
def update_fig(selected_housing, selected_quartiles, selected_re, selected_age, selected_dname, selected_county):
  gdff_1 = gdf_final_serial[gdf_final_serial.CountyName.isin(selected_county) & 
                            gdf_final_serial.DistrictName.isin(selected_dname) &
                            gdf_final_serial.Age.isin(selected_age) &
                            gdf_final_serial.RE.isin(selected_re) &
                            gdf_final_serial.QUARTILES.isin(selected_quartiles) & 
                            gdf_final_serial.HOUSING_INSECURE.isin(selected_housing)]
  count_points = gdff_1.groupby("OBJECTID").size().rename("points")
  gdf_last = gdff_1.merge(count_points, on="OBJECTID", how="right", right_index = True)
  gdf_last.to_pickle(root_path+"gdf_last") #Write to drive as a pickle to serialize
  ddf_final_serial = pd.read_pickle(root_path+"gdf_last") #Read as DataFrame
  gddf_final_serial = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data = ddf_final_serial, geometry= "geometry", crs = "epsg:4326")
  gdff_2 = gddf_final_serial.head(50)
  px.set_mapbox_access_token(mapbox_access_token)
  fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(data_frame= gdff_2,
                             geojson= geo_school,
                             locations= 'DistrictName',
                             featureidkey = 'properties.DistrictName',
                             color="points",
                             center={"lat": 38.5941, "lon": -119.8815}, 
                             mapbox_style = 'dark').update_layout(mapbox_accesstoken =  mapbox_access_token)
  return fig
# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run_server(host="127.0.0.1", port="8888",debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I've been able to receive various conditions where the map/filter will produce a single county, sometimes two counties-- but never the whole shebang. Keep in mind my ultimate goal is to create this for the **ENTIRE** dataset (maybe using RapidsAI from NVIDIA; however i'm having trouble installing that as well within Google Colab).

What's more interesting is that when I run this code outside of dash (as a sample of the actual dataset) and pass it to fig.show(), it will show up; however, it won't work in the Dash app.

I suspect that the issue is either with my json handling or the final callback as the debugger indicates that while the inputs are there, my_map.figure isn't outputting the data. I appreciate the help.

Comment: My answer my guide you, and not be what you want to hear.  Please do reach out on the RAPIDS GoAi slack, because I'd love to see what you build :) . https://join.slack.com/t/rapids-goai/shared_invite/zt-trnsul8g-Sblci8dk6dIoEeGpoFcFOQ

Answer (score 0):

1. It is hard to impossible currently do what you want in Colab because [Plot.ly dash will run `inline`](https://analyticsindiamag.com/how-to-use-plotly-in-colab/), but NOT as a Dash `app dashboard` due to the access restrictions Colab currently has for its instances.  [You should be using the RAPIDS install template for Colab, btw](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rY7Ln6rEE1pOlfSHCYOVaqt8OvDO35J0#forceEdit=true&offline=true&sandboxMode=true).
2. [We have something working similar to what you're working on, deployed in paperspace](https://blog.paperspace.com/webapp-nvidia-rapids-plot-ly/).  We created a [RAPIDS based tutorial](https://ml-showcase.paperspace.com/projects/interactive-ml-app-rapids-plotly).  You can also [take the code and deploy it](https://github.com/taureandyernv/rapids-plotly-webapps) elsewhere, if you'd like.